# D3 Dendrogram - Not shown

Tags: d3.js, dendrogram

I'm trying to work with a Dendrogram from the D3 library. I understand the example as far, but I can't see anything while viewing the file in the browser. It's just a white screen. Can someone help me how to show the figure?
Or do you need further information?

Thanks allready for your help!

Here is the link to the project: [Dendrogram D3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are javascripts error with generation your `dendrogram`.
What browser do you use? If it's chrome press `F12` to debug your web page and see where error is.

If you just copied `html` example most likely you've missed json file invoked inside of this example `/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json`

Comment: I took an other json-file and it should be correct as well (from here:http://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/dendrogramma-d3-parte1/)
I'm using Firefox ...